# How to access the TestRail API behind basic authentication plus form based authentication?

Tags: automated-testing, api, testrail

I’m trying to access the API of TestRail (by gurock) on our self-hosted TestRail server (version v5.1.0.3413). To use TestRail, we have to login with basic authentication plus form-based authentication. The sample call in the API documentation uses `curl -u …` to handle basic authentication. But this just gives me following error:

```
{“error”:“Authentication failed: invalid or missing user/password or session cookie.”}
```

I guess this is because I somehow have to provide the form-based login credentials. Has anybody here handled this scenario of TestRail API access with basic plus form-based authentication before?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does the trick for me.

```
# Login
curl -u basicUser:basicPassword -c cookies -d "name=formUser&password=formPassword" -X POST "https://testrailserver/index.php?/auth/login"

# Get test statuses
curl  -u basicUser:basicPassword -b cookies -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://testrailserver/index.php?/api/v2/get_statuses"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone still face this problem (e.g. me).

I've found that you have to press **Save Settings** after adding an API keys

- Not saved: [image]
- Saved: [image]